# Send email with Visual Studio 2010 c# and external SMTP server

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio-2010

I've a VS.STUDIO 2010 C# project where i'm trying to send email using my SMTP remote server
I always have a Timeout and no email sent, looking SMTP logs there's no access attempt from my IP , this is my code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

private void EmailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CompanySelected))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invio email in corso per: " + CompanySelected, "Avviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                SettingsManager SettMngr = new SettingsManager();
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = SettMngr.SmtpHost.Trim(),
                    Port = Convert.ToInt16(SettMngr.SmtpPort),
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SettMngr.SmtpUser, SettMngr.SmtpPassword),
                    Timeout = 50000
             
                };
                mail.From = new MailAddress("server@ashnet.it");
                mail.To.Add("info@ashnet.it");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail - SERVICE 2020";
                mail.Body = "mail with attachment";
                string file = "c:\\service_tmp\\q_attuali Natana_Jolly.xlsx";
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));

                try
                {
                    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                }
                catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ex.InnerExceptions.Length; i++)
                    {
                        SmtpStatusCode status = ex.InnerExceptions[i].StatusCode;
                        if (status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||
                            status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Delivery failed - retrying in 5 seconds.");
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Failed to deliver message to {0}",
                                ex.InnerExceptions[i].FailedRecipient);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): {0}",
                            ex.ToString());
                }

        }
```

I run code and all it's ok until send(mail) , all smtp parameters are right
send(mail) wait some time and then exit with a Timeout error
Also increasing timeout values does'nt solve problems

Thanks

Comment: Check you mail server webpage for SMTP settings.  The port number could be wrong.  The Credentials and the fromaddress need to use the same email account..  Also SMTP will not work to an outside email server like gmail if you are inside a company network that has an outlook email server.  So try from your home PC.

Comment: the SMTP is a my server and all parameters are correct :(

Comment: Does code work when on same machine as SMTP Server?  Do you have a firewall or virus checker blocking the port?  Do you have an outlook server on the network?  When an Outlook Server is on the network all port 587 is forwarded at firewall to a Proxy Server and then Credentials are verified before being send to the local outlook server.

Comment: My VS app is running on my dev pc that is connected to Internet and i've no filter for output traffic, my SMTP server is a public server where i've all my 1k users..

Comment: The you first response is wrong.  I said " Check you mail server webpage for SMTP settings."  Is the public server an email service like gmail or are you the administrator?

Comment: Sorry.. yes i'm an administrator

Comment: Lastly I realized that it only works using port 25 and with ssl = false, this although I am sure my server accepts ssl connections on ports 465 and 587

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: ok thanks, i've to find a way to use ssl because my smtp server don't to like msg coming from port 25